# Solving singular sparse matrix MATLAB

Tags: matlab, sparse-matrix

I have a large sparse matrix that I'm working on, but for simplicity I have written it below as shown:

```
row = [1,3];
col = [1,3];
val = [22,33];

B = sparse(row,col,val,3,3)

22     0     0
 0     0     0
 0     0    33
```

This matrix is singular and does not have an inverse that I can use for a solution of:

`[A]=[B][C]` => `[B]\[A] = [C]`.

To remedy this, all of the rows and columns containing only zero need to be removed. So, in the example above, I would remove row 2 and column 2 before I create the sparse matrix.

But if I try this, the index described by the row and col vectors (3,3) will point outside the matrix dimensions and give me an error.
What is something I can do to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could first construct your matrix the way that you have, and then remove the empty rows and columns with the following

```
C = B(any(B, 2), any(B, 1));
```

This is very efficient (space-wise) since `any` applied to a sparse matrix yields a sparse result and the indexing operation above yields `C` which is *also* sparse

Although, depending on your problem, this will not guarantee a non-singular matrix.

**Update**

If you want to remove a row or column if both the row and corresponding column are zero (to keep your matrix square)

```
tokeep = any(B, 2).' | any(B, 1);

C = B(tokeep, tokeep);
```

Comment: Isn't this an incredibly inefficient method when dealing with large sparse matrices (1000000x1000000)?

Comment: @Lobstw No because all intermediate values are also `sparse`

Comment: Thank you for clarifying. However, this does not produce the expected results for a case such as: `[22 0 0;44 0 0;0 0 33]` the 2nd row should not be removed

Comment: @Lobstw I think you meant second column. I have an updated option.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution

```
row = [1,3];
col = [1,3];
val = [22,33];
[ur,~,u_row] =  unique(row);
[uc,~,u_col] =  unique(col);
B =sparse( u_row,u_col,val,numel(ur),numel(uc));
```